# Multiple elements using a slideToggle function

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

This is a code im using. I know i'm a noob, i dont know nothing about javascript/jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $("[class='panel']").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.panel, .flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
 float:left;
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left">
    <a href="#" class="flip 56">1</a>
    <div class='panel'>Hello world 1!</div>
    <br />

    <div style="display:block; border:1px solid #000">
        Get down
    </div>
    <br />

    <a href="#" class="flip 50">2</a>
    <div class='panel'>Hello world 2!</div>
    <div style="display:block; border:1px solid #000; position:relative">
        Get down again!
    </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t930sx4d/

I'm trying to make it look like in the picture below. I tried to put an unique id and use "this". It didn't worked.
Thank you in advance!

[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4hkM.jpg)

Comment: I can't believe it. A newbie who asks a good question and provides not only all their code, but also a Fiddle, an illustration image and an inline-working demo. You deserve the "best newbie ever" badge. We're gonna get you out of the woods :) Give me a minute

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, it was exactly what i was looking for! I cant vote because it requires 15 reputation but i thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. You were actually pretty close. Use `$(this).next()` to target the element next to the clicked one. I have also made some minor adjustments. The "float:left" on panels was harming your layout a lot. Float is a strange property that kinda dismembers elements and can mess everything up. It has to be used only when necessary.

```js
$(".flip").click(function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.panel, .flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}

.hint{
 border : black solid 1px; 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left">
    <a href="#" class="flip">1</a>
    <div class='panel'>Hello world 1!</div>

    <div class="hint">
        Get down
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
  
    <a href="#" class="flip 50">2</a>
    <div class='panel'>Hello world 2!</div>
    <div class="hint">
        Get down again!
    </div>

</div>
```